# error C2065: необъявленный идентификатор

Tags: c++, visual-c++

Была программа (которая считает стоимость всех компьюеров на складе, а также выодит инфу о компьютере с самой высокой тактовой частотой процессора стоимостью от 20 до 30к):

```
#include <locale>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

struct computer
{

    char cpu_brand[10];
    unsigned int cpu_clock;
    char motherboard[10];
    char harddrive[10];
    char videoacrd[10];
    char wifi[10];
    unsigned int price;
    unsigned int store;

    void getInfo()
    {
        cout << " Brand of CPU: " << cpu_brand << endl;
        cout << " CPU clock in Mhz: " << cpu_clock << endl;
        cout << " Brand of motherboard: " << motherboard << endl;
        cout << " Brand of HDD: " << harddrive << endl;
        cout << " Brand of GPU: " << videoacrd << endl;
        cout << " Presence of wi-fi: " << wifi << endl;
        cout << " Cost of computer: " << price << endl;
        cout << " Quantity in stock: " << store << endl;
    }
};

const int N = 3;

computer collection[N]; // создаем массив из N структур computer

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    {
        printf("\n\nEnter info abot computer №%d\n", i + 1);

        printf(" Brand of CPU - ");
        std::cin.getline(collection[i].cpu_brand, 10);

        printf(" CPU clock in Mhz - ");
        scanf_s("%u", &collection[i].cpu_clock);
        getchar();

        printf(" Brand of motherboard - ");
        std::cin.getline(collection[i].motherboard, 10);

        printf(" Brand of HDD - ");
        std::cin.getline(collection[i].harddrive, 10);

        printf(" Brand of GPU - ");
        std::cin.getline(collection[i].videoacrd, 10);

        printf(" Presence of wi-fi - ");
        std::cin.getline(collection[i].wifi, 10);

        printf(" Cost of computer - ");
        scanf_s("%u", &collection[i].price);
        getchar();

        printf(" Quantity in stock - ");
        scanf_s("%u", &collection[i].store);
        getchar();
    }


    int S;
    int SS = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        S = collection[i].price * collection[i].store;
        SS = SS + S;
    }
    cout << "Cost of all computers in a store " << SS << endl;



    computer buff = collection[0]; // будем хранить объект струтктуры вместо числа
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (collection[i].price < 30000 || collection[i].price > 20000) {
            if (buff.cpu_clock < collection[i].cpu_clock) {
                buff = collection[i];
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "The computer with the highest processor clock cost from 20 to 30 t.r: " << endl;
    buff.getInfo(); // получаем информацию о компьютере

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}
```

Потребовалось переделать ее так, чтобы данные считывались из файла, вместо char был string,была реализована динамическая память.
Получилось следующее:

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <locale> 
#include <string> 
#include <fstream> 

using namespace std;

struct computer
{

    string cpu_brand;
    unsigned int cpu_clock;
    string motherboard;
    string harddrive;
    string videoacrd;
    string wifi;
    unsigned int price;
    unsigned int store;

    void getInfo()
    {
        cout << " Производитель процессора: " << cpu_brand << endl;
        cout << " Частота процессора в МГц: " << cpu_clock << endl;
        cout << " Производитель материнской платы: " << motherboard << endl;
        cout << " Производитель HDD: " << harddrive << endl;
        cout << " Производитель видеокарты: " << videoacrd << endl;
        cout << " Наличие wifi: " << wifi << endl;
        cout << " Стоимость компьютера: " << price << endl;
        cout << " Количество компьютеров на складе: " << store << endl;
    }
};


computer FileRead(ifstream &file)
{
    computer acomputer;
    getline(file, acpu_brand);
    file >> acpu_clock;
    getline(file, amotherboard);
    getline(file, aharddrive);
    getline(file, avideoacrd);
    getline(file, awifi);
    file >> aprice;
    file >> astore;

    return acomputer;
}

void FileInfo(computer acomputer, int i)
{
    cout << "\n\n Данные для компютера №" << (i + 1) << endl;
    cout << " Производитель процессора - " << acpu_brand << endl;
    cout << " Частота процессора в МГц - " << acpu_clock << endl;
    cout << " Производитель материнской платы - " << amotherboard << endl;
    cout << " Производитель HDD - " << aharddrive << endl;
    cout << " Производитель видеокарты  - " << avideoacrd << endl;
    cout << " Наличие wifi - " << awifi << endl;
    cout << " Стоимость компьютера - " << aprice << endl;
    cout << " Количество компьютеров на складе - " << astore << endl;
}


void CostOf(computer *collection, int N, string aprice, string astore)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        int S;
    int SS = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        S = collection[i].price * collection[i].store;
        SS = SS + S;
    }
    cout << "Стоимость всех компьютеров на складе " << SS << endl;
}


void MaxClock(computer *collection, int N, string aprice, string acpu_clock)
{
    computer buff = collection[0]; // будем хранить объект струтктуры вместо числа
    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
        if (collection[i].price < 30000 || collection[i].price > 20000) {
            if (buff.cpu_clock < collection[i].cpu_clock) {
                buff = collection[i];
            }
        }
    }

    cout << "Компьютер с самой высокой тактовой частотой процессора стоимостью от 20 до 30 тр: " << endl;
    buff.getInfo(); // получаем информацию о компьютере
}

int main()
{
    setlocale(LC_ALL, "rus");

    ifstream infile;
    infile.open("file.txt");
    int N;
    infile >> N;
    collection = new computer[N];

    for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
        collection[i] = FlleRead(infile);

    for (int i = 0; i < N, i++)
        FileInfo(collection[i], i)

    CostOf(collection, N);
    MaxClock(collection, N);

    delete[] collection;
    infile.close();
    system("pause");
    return 0;
```

Теперь не могу понять, почему программа не хочет запускаться. В VS создал консольное приложение, в папку закинул файл, но все равно выдет кучу ошибок. Если в коде ошибку, то я походу ее  в упор не замечаю.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ну вот почему здесь `std::cin.getline(collection[i].cpu_brand, 10);` вы указывали объект, у которого поле `cpu_brand`, а вот тут - `getline(file, acpu_brand);` - нет?

Тут

```
computer acomputer;
getline(file, acpu_brand);
file >> acpu_clock;
```

ваш `acomputer` в принципе не изменяется.

А, ладно, что я намеками - все эти `acpu_brand` замените на `acomputer.acpu_brand`?

А вообще у вас весь код - одна большая ошибка. Добавленная буква `a` перед именами, отсутствие указания объектов у полей, не объявленные идентификаторы, жуть типа

```
for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
    int S;
```

Начните заново...

P.S. Только честно - взяли чью-то чужую программу и решили быстренько поменять и спихнуть как свою? *Не ваша* была первая программа...

Comment: 1-я была моя, помогли только с выводом информации о компьютере (где buff). За то, что указали на ошибки, отдельное спасибо. Пойду с нуля делать